# REST Dynamic URI

Tags: api, rest, uri, hateoas

Can a hyperlink in a REST response contain reference to the result of a differing attribut in the response?

For example, I'm attempting to design an API response that has a link to gather statements for the previous six months, but I want this URI to be relative to the start_date of the statement returned in the original GET request.

```
"start_date" : “12/1/13”,
"end_date" : “12/31/13”,
"previous_enrollments" : {
   "name" : “enrollment_history”,
   "title" : “Previous Six Months”
   "link" : "/offers/1004/enrollments?", // Where start date is 6 months prior to the        current response
   "rel" = "self",
   "method": "GET",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, that's one of the core tenets and benefits of HATEOAS.

However your URI looks incomplete with that trailing "?" on it. You should probably return the entire URI - parameters included - that they can blindly GET without having to parse and manipulate it in order to follow it. For example:

`"link" : "/offers/1004/enrollments?start=1/1/13&end="7/1/13`